# How do I use scorestreaks?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I unlocked a whole bunch of scorestreaks in the past few days, but I have no clue on how to use them. Is there a certain objective you have to accomplish in order to use them, or can they be activated with the press of a certain button? I'm on PS3 by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Scorestreaks must be unlocked and selected out at the root menu of the multiplayer interface, shown here:

[image: Scorestreaks]

Note that once you enter that menu, you will see all of the Scorestreaks available for your level - but you may still need to spend tokens to unlock Scorestreaks which you have not previously unlocked, in order to make them "selectable".  This is straightforward, and there are on screen indicators of Scorestreaks that require you to spend unlock tokens.

A few other possibly relevant details:

- You accrue "points" during each round for doing basically anything - killing a foe, having a UAV up while others kill foes, shooting down a UAV, etc.
- You may only have 3 Scorestreaks "activated" at any time.
- Each Scorestreak has a required point total.  Hit that total, when that Scorestreak is activated, and you'll get access to that Scorestreak for use immediately during that round.
- An onscreen indication appears when you have earned enough points for a Scorestreak.  I don't play on PS3, but I suspect that like XBox you'll need to D-pad right to select that Scorestreak and then for some Scorestreaks hitting the "use" button is also necessary ("X" on XBox).
- Scorestreak points reset each time you die.  If you don't get enough points, it's possible to go a whole round without getting a Scorestreak.

Comment: @jonathanbell Glad it helped you.