# Can you select which scorestreak reward to activate?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

When I get a number of scorestreaks at once, can you select which one to activate? Is it always the most recent streak rewarded?

My scorestreak combo is care package, counter-UAV, and the Guardian. They all unlock at or around the same score and the Guardian gets activated first, where I would ideally like to save that one for later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very similar to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97007/how-do-i-use-scorestreaks), but I'll take it you are looking for the nuance of "can I decide the order I use scorestreaks".  To answer your direct question, you can "cursor" up and down through your scorestreaks to select which one you want to activate, once you have more than one choice.  This is done with the D-pad on XBox, and I presume it is similar on PS3.  On PC it could simply be the cursor keys, but you may have to check the key bindings if that is your platform of choice.